# Calculate amount of disk space used by results of a T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am comparing SQL Server with another database technology, and in order to compare disk requirements I would like to calculate the amount of disk used by only the elements returned by a SELECT query that JOINs over a few tables with a simple WHERE clause, rather than for a whole table or database. This is so that I don't have to go to the trouble of loading an entire table or database worth of data into the other database.

I have a query like the following that I'd like to do this for:

```
SELECT * FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
INNER JOIN d ON a.id = d.id1 OR a.id = d.id2
WHERE a.id = 390330
```

I haven't been able to find any advice online, other than how to find the disk space used by an entire table or database. Is there anything built into SQL Server that can help me, or will I need to calculate this by hand?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't really use "disk space".  It uses table spaces that are stored on disk and the allocation is controlled by the server -- and one option is partitions that grow as needed.

Comment: Ok, good point - would I be able to get a reasonable estimate (an estimate is all I need here) by loading the selected data into a new table and measuring the size of that?

Comment: What do you want to calculate? row size * number of rows? Or specifically "disk usage"? Resultsets are not directed to hard drive - there is now "result set disk usage". However, during query execution server reads from drive, server may write to drive (like tempdb).

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is how much space the rows that are returned are occupying on disk. I could find out how much disk space is used by an entire table, but I want to get an estimate of how much disk space is used by a subset of several tables (defined by the query).

Comment: Thank you for repeating your original question. When do you expect returned rows to be put on disk?

Comment: row size * number of rows sounds more like what I want. How can I calculate row size?

Comment: _this_ question can be answered by google. MSDN has specific pages for each mssql version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An estimate for the storage needed to store a subset of rows can be calculated by collecting the sizes of the rows. Although this is infeasible to do in a generic fashion for an arbitrary query with several joins, for specifically the query in the question you can build up a query that will calculate the size of all of the rows included in the query like so (based on code from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/calculate-row-size-of-a-table-in-sqlserver1):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);  

set @sql = '
SELECT COALESCE((
    --table a
    SELECT SUM(0' 

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)'  
    from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('a')  

set @sql = @sql + ')
    FROM a
    WHERE a.id = 390330
), 0) + COALESCE((
    -- table b
    SELECT SUM(0'  

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)'  
    from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('b')  

set @sql = @sql + ')
    FROM b
    WHERE b.id = 390330
), 0) + COALESCE((
    -- table c
    SELECT SUM(0'  

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)'  
    from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('c')  

set @sql = @sql + ')
    FROM c
    WHERE c.id = 390330
), 0) + COALESCE((
    -- table d
    SELECT SUM(0'  

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)'  
    from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('d')  

set @sql = @sql + ')
    FROM d
    WHERE d.id1 = 390330 OR d.id2 = 390330
), 0);

exec (@sql);
```